# How to delete "[","]" in dataframe? and How i paste dataframe to existing excel file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm very new to python. I think it's very simple thing but I can't. What I have to do is removing some strings of one column's each value from specific strings.

| available_list |
| --- |
| AE,SG,MO |
| KR,CN |
| SG |
| MO,MY |

```
all_list = 'AE,SG,MO,MY,KR,CN,US,HK,YS'
```

I want to remove available_list values from all_list.
What I tried is following code.

```
col1 = df['available_list']
all_ori = 'AE,SG,MO,MY,KR,CN,US,HK,YS'.split(',')
all_c = all_ori.copy()
result=[]

for i in col1:
    for s in i:
        all_c.remove(s)
    result.append(all_c)
    all_c = all_main.copy()

result_df = pd.DataFrame({'Non-Priviliges' : result})
```

But the result was,

```
|Non-Priviliges|
|[MY, KR, CN, US, HK, YS]|
|[SG, MO, US, HK, YS]|
|[AE, SG, KR, CN, US, HK, YS]|
```

The problems are "[", "]". How I remove them?

And after replacing them,
I want to paste this series to existing excel file, next-to the column named "Priviliges".

Could you give me some advice? thanks!

Comment: from your example, it is understandable from my side that output is going to be YS,HK, US. But how you want to write back to excel ? one row for each value or all values will be in a single row ?

Comment: i want to get each value for rows! my desired result is each row’s non privilege countries. sorry for my unclear question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your filename is "hello.xlsx", Following is my answer:

```
import pandas as pd
        
df = pd.read_excel('hello.xlsx')
        
all_list_str = 'AE,SG,MO,MY,KR,CN,US,HK,YS'
all_list = all_list_str.split(',')
        
def find_non_priv(row):
    #convert row item string value to list
    row_list = row.split(',')
    return ','.join(list(set(all_list) - set(row_list)))
        
# pandas apply is used to call function to each row items.
df['Non-Priviliges'] = df['available_list'].apply(find_non_priv)
        
df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

Comment: thanks it works. i didn't know apply method. it can modify data by column-wise.